# Internal Server Error when sending JSON object to .NET webservice

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, web-services

I have a problem submitting a complex JSON object to a .NET web service.

The Ajax JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: WEBSERVICE_ADMINISTRATIO_URL + "RecieveData",

    data: JSON.stringify({data: _data}), // _data is the Javascipt object {}
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

The .NET webservice

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string RecieveData(string data)
    {

        return "";
    }
```

I get an **Internal Server Error 500** when trying to submit the data to the webservice from the client.

I have other webservice function that just return data and they work fine. I gave both GET and POST permission in the web.config.

Here's the detailed error:

```
"{"Message":"No parameterless constructor defined for type of 
 \u0027System.String\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at 
system.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException"}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: ...and what have you tried to debug this? Have you turned on some verbose error messages? Perhaps added a breakpoint and stepped into the method? ... "Internal Server Error" is just the default 500 response code. That means _something_ went wrong - you're going to have to help us out by telling us what that is.

Comment: I get the error in the console in Chrome and the code returns to the "error" function of the $.ajax call. Is happens at the $.ajax call line where I call to the webservice (the exact Javascipt code I've shown above). The webservice code is as simple as possible. I therefore assume that it's an issue with how the data is sent to the webservice.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that javascript error function and inspect the rest of the variables. If they give you only the generic `500 - Internal Server Error` response then you need to enable some more verbose error messages on the .NET side. Perhaps forcefully turn `<customErrors mode="Off" />` so that you get an ugly stack trace telling you more information. Your question is unanswerable given that `Internal Server Error` could mean absolutely anything :/

Comment: Try to send your `data` without *stringifying* it...

Comment: @L.B sending the data without the stringify gives the same error (500)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I've added the detailed error into the question body.

Comment: Much better. Is your data valid JSON? I've seen this error happen when you haven't put quotes around your JSON properties. E.g, you did this: `{ Name: "Simon" }` when it _must be_ this: `{ "Name": "Simon" }`.

Comment: @Simon the _data is a JS object. So how can I make something wrong when stringifying it. Maybe I need to convert it to JSON first before stringifying it?

Comment: Thats one option. The other option is to actually create a proper model on the .NET side that it can bind to (instead of just `string`).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Stfingify already convert the object to JSON. I ran the JSON in JSLint to see if it passes validation and it does. All the attribute keys has quotes, and as I said, it passes validation. So I don't understand why .Net can't serialize it :( BTW: when I send a simple string ("a"), the webservice is called successfully, so the problem, is that .NET can't serialize my valid JSON.  Can I have an empty [] as the data or I must have it field with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your support. I was able to solve this by changing the parameter data type from string to Object.

```
 public string RecieveData(Object data)
{

    return "";
}
```